# why i am getting error while accessing the jenkins homepage?

Tags: jenkins, vpn

I am not able to display the jenkins homepage properly.
I have installed two VM with jenkins server and accessing the jenkins through putty and windows browser. Scenarion of two jenkins are

1. with normal connection [working]
2. in vpn connection [not working]

i can view the homepage of 1st, but not getting proper view of 2nd machine.
It displays only text not working. I mean only texts of login ,logout and build now etc. 
when i click on this text getting following error

"Not Found

The requested URL /login was not found on this server."

There is no browser issues i have tried it 2-3 browsers.
I think this is jenkins issues or something else plz help.

Answer (score 0):

You share so few details about how you installed Jenkins and what is the environment that you should not expect any good answers. I suspect the problem is around the correct use of the Jenkins --prefix command line parameter. It changes the way Jenkins constructs URLs for links. I hope this helps. If not, you should consider telling us more about your setup.

Comment: It's working now..i had added / jenkins in jenkins.conf file before http://localhost:8080
I was accessing it in wrong way. Thanks. 
I can not share the images bcz of reputation less than 10. :(